# Tableau, how to remove legend

Tags: legend, tableau-api

I have workbook on [Public Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/DailySelf-Study/DailySelf-Study) to keep track of daily studytime.

I didn't study yesterday :-( so I want it to show zero.

However, it appears in legend as Null

This is my data

[image]

And this is the graph. I circled part of legend that I wish to remove. Please assist.

[image]

Comment: How are you loading the data into Tableau? Is it just an Excel worksheet? Are you doing anything fancy, or just straight up importing the file?

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise Just straight-up importing from Excel

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise I just realized I copied and pasted the wrong excel data. Reposting.....

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise Any ideas? My only option would be to manually say 0 minutes for both `Book` and `Network Simulation`

Answer (score 4):

You can right click on the null in the legend and select "exclude" that will hide it.

Also, I wanted to point out that this null is not coming from the zero in your data it is coming from a missing value in the "method" column.

Comment: If I hide it, then it doesn't show September 27, 2015. I wish to show it being zero. Only workaround was to manually add 0 to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Any ideas? My only option would be to manually say 0 minutes for both `Book` and `Network Simulation`

Comment: @emh has the exact right idea. To keep that missing date in there, just right click on `MDY(Date)` and check **Show Missing Values**.

Answer (score 2):

To remove legends you can Drag "method" into filters and unmark null from the filters so this will not display Null in legends.

Refer this link to view output[image: Remove null from legends]

In your Example you have to drag "Method" in place of Quantity in my example and uncheck "Null" from the filter You will get desired results.